# Passing column names into graph function in ggplot2

Tags: r, function, graph, tidyr

I have a large dataset with multiple dependent variables but with only two independent variables (that I will be using over and over again to sort the many dependent variables). Each of the dependent variables was measured twice, once before and once after treatment. I would like to write a function that allows me to obtain a graph for each of these multiple dependent variables, with the arguments of the function as the two column names for whichever of the dependent variables i wish to graph.

I have generated a toy dataset to illustrate my problem. 't1DV1' and 't1DV2' are the pre- and post- treatment scores for dependent variable 1. 't1DV2' and 't2DV2' are pre- and post- treatment scores for dependent variable 2. 'group' is the independent variable.

```
group <- factor(rep(c("A", "B"), 10))
t1DV1 <- runif(20, min = 0, max = 10)
t2DV1 <- runif(20, min = 0, max = 10)
t1DV2 <- runif(20, min = 0, max = 10)
t2DV2 <- runif(20, min = 0, max = 10)

df <- data.frame(group, t1DV1, t2DV1, t1DV2, t2DV2)

df
```

I tried writing the following function

```
DVGraph <- function (DV1, DV2) { 

require(tidyr)

dfLong <- gather(df, prePost, Score, DV1:DV1)

require(ggplot2)

barGraph <- ggplot(dfLong, aes(group, Score, fill = prePost)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#666666")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Scores") +
  theme_bw()

return(barGraph)

}
```

And then tried calling it using the first of the repeated measures variables (I could equally have used the second, i.e. t1DV2 and t2DV2)

```
DVGraph(t1DV1, t2DV1)
```

But I get an error.

I tried using inverted commas like so

```
DVGraph("t1DV1", "t2DV1")
```

But i got another (different) error.

Does anyone know how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your `gather` call to the following:

```
dfLong <- gather(df, prePost, Score, DV1, DV2)
```

Then when you call your function, use the column numbers instead of the column names:

```
DVGraph(2, 3)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can replace `gather()` with `melt()` from `reshape2` with `substitute()` in order to be able to call the function with the unquoted variables:

```
DVGraph <- function (DV1, DV2) { 

  require(tidyr)
  require(reshape2)

  dfLong <- melt(df,measure.vars = c(substitute(DV1),substitute(DV2)),
                 var="prePost",value.name ="Score")

  require(ggplot2)

  barGraph <- ggplot(dfLong, aes(group, Score, fill = prePost)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", size = 0.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#666666")) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Scores") +
    theme_bw()

  return(barGraph)

}

DVGraph(t1DV2, t2DV1)
```

**Update:**

If you want to do what you asked about in your comment, one quick fix is to recognize that using `substitute()` forces your vector to be a list, but you can force it to be a character by using `as.character(substitute())` as follows:

```
createFrame <- function (DV1, DV2) { 
  extractCols <- c("group", as.character(substitute(DV1)), as.character(substitute(DV2)))
  newFrame <- df[,extractCols]
  return(newFrame) 
}

createFrame(t1DV1, t2DV1)
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! Worked a treat.

Comment: Sam, I have a lot of variables in my dataset. A LOT. So in addition to the above I really need a way of creating a reduced version of my dataframe within the function above. Using the principles of the 'substitute' function you showed me above i tried this:

  
      createFrame <- function (DV1, DV2) {
  
      extractCols <- c("group", substitute(DV1), substitute(DV2))
  
      newFrame <- df[,extractCols]
  
      return(newFrame)
    }

createFrame(t1DV1, t2DV1)

But this does not work. 

Any idea how I might do this? Or is this perhaps a separate question for the boards?